# fancybox pop-up page not opening second time on iframe mode

Tags: jquery, iframe, popup, fancybox

I have:

```
$(".fancybox-href").click(function () {
    $.fancybox({
        'title': this.href,
        'width': 800,
        'height': 600,
        'href': this.href,
        'type': 'iframe'
    });
    return false;
});
```

on my document ready section;

and i have popup function as:

```
function PopupOnClose(navigateObject, performCallbackTo) {
$.fancybox({
    'title': navigateObject.href,
    'width': 800,
    'height': 600,
    'href': navigateObject.href,
    'type': 'iframe',
    onClosed: function () {
        if (performCallbackTo != null) {
            eval(performCallbackTo + ".PerformCallback()");
        }
    }
});
return false;
```

}

and on my trigger link i have:

```
  <a id="my-popup" class="fancybox-href" onclick="PopupOnClose(this,'DxCallbackMyAspXCallBackPanel')" href="/My-PopUp-Page.aspx" ></a>
```

and my problem is maybe as you expected :

The Fancybox does not open the second time. when I click the first time fancybox shows up,  but it does not fire up second time:

actually when I clicked second time, it waits and the fancybox modal window is appearing a very short time, but afterwards, the browser is redirecting to the page "My-PopUp-Page.aspx" directly.

help please.

thanks.

P.S: PerformCallback is a devexpress event and the problem that I specified is independent with it. That process is working well.

Comment: Don't really understand why you are trying to fire fancybox with two different methods at the same time.

Comment: Bacuse i dont know how can i pass a parameter like "function PopupOnClose(navigateObject, performCallbackTo) {" function's signature on first setting block? :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation is done. Problem was initialize fancybox with an OnClose function and its done with following:

```
$(".fancybox-href").click(function (navigateObject, performCallbackTo) {
$.fancybox({
    'title': this.href,
    'width': 800,
    'height': 600,
    'href': this.href,
    'type': 'iframe',
onClosed: function () {
    if (performCallbackTo != null) {
        eval(performCallbackTo + ".PerformCallback()");
    }
});
return false;});
```

Thanx everybody..